# Замена сервера на Android

Tags: android, сервер

Всем привет, может кто-то сталкивался с данным вопрос, где можно хранить данные пользователя, то есть например в игре есть валюта, пользователь сколько-то заработал, потом удалил приложения, затем через неделю снова установил и старые данные подтянулись, может есть какой-то сервис хранения данных или что-то вроде того, что бы самому не делать и не брать в аренду сервер.на Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо чтобы у каждого юзера был уникальный идентификатор. Например ID в к-л соц.сети. После этого вы можете сохранять где-то пару ключ/значение вида `ID:value`

Сохранять можно по разному. Например вы можете просто редактировать текстовый файл в к-л вашем облаке (GDrive, DropBox etc). Но лучше, воспользоваться к-л бесплатным (условно) облаком типа FireBase. В последнем данные хранятся в виде JSON файла и есть библиотека для простой записи/получения значений. Но бесплатно там до определённого порога кол-ва соединений с облаком в секунду.